# Tag wiki edit awarded double rep

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tag-wiki-suggestion

So I proposed an edit to a tag wiki ([this one](https://superuser.com/tags/dns/info) not that it really matters) and I got 2 +2s when the edit was accepted.

Pretty sure this is a bug.

Answer (score 3):

It occurred to me that I also edited the excerpt. Is that what is going on here (+2 for the excerpt edit, and +2 for the tag wiki body edit)?

Comment: yes, that's what it is.

Answer (score 2):

You got +2 for the excerpt & another +2 for the body.